# JSTL 1.2 The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved

Tags: jsp, jstl, taglib

I am getting this error *org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this applicationj
I do have the javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar and the javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder . Below is the taglib import in JSP .

taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"

taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"

Comment: When and where exactly do you see this error? Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Do you have any other lib in the deployment mimicking jstl?

Comment: I get this error when I lauch the JSP ..the only other jar I have in the lib other than these is mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin

Comment: @BalusC  Let me know you need any info ...I am just using basic jsp to connect to a mySQL server ..nothing fancy ...

Comment: It did work for me ..I replaced the jar with jstl1-2.jar instead of the servlet version and it did work ...:)